# How to change flask form output with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm creating a simple flask app which generates output based on a data added to a flask form. What I'm trying to achieve is possibility to edit that output and in the same time update the other values based on that changes. App is calculating working hours, so I need to allow edition of the fields like begin of work and so on. Then those changes need to reflect the sum of total hours per day.
Here is the output page:

[image]

On above example I would like to change for example beginning of work to 10:00 and expect the total Number of hours to reduce from 8 to 7.
I hope you know what I mean guys.

Here is example of a div table that I use:

```html
<div class="rTableRow" align="center">
  <div class="rTableCell">{{ day['day'].strftime("%d") }}</div>
  <div class="rTableCell">{{ day['day'].strftime("%a") }}</div>
  <div class="rTableCell" contenteditable="true">{{ day['absence'] }}</div>
  <div class="rTableCell" contenteditable="true">{{ day['start-hour'] }}</div>
  <div class="rTableCell" contenteditable="true">{{ day['end-hour'] }}</div>
  <div class="rTableCell" contenteditable="true">{{ day['additional-break'] }}</div>
  <div class="rTableCell" contenteditable="true">{{ day['overtime'] }}</div>
  <div class="rTableCell" contenteditable="true">{{ day['daily-total'] if day['daily-total'] != 0 else '-' }}</div>
```

Is there a way to do it with JavaScript? All the data is processed on view level and passed to a template.

Many thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkjwgy10/36/

Here's an example on how to do it through `javascript`. Some assumptions I assumed were that

- you validated the data on input
- you incorporated `jQuery`. You can also do it through just `javascript`, but you would then need to add in `eventListeners`. Documentation on jQuery can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/).
- you had your own CSS to create tables -- the jsFiddle will show top-down format, as I didn't include any CSS.

Some considerations:

- instead of writing your own hours calculations, you could use `moment.js` -- documentation for that is [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/).
- consider having another attribute called `value` that holds information that will be used by Flask, but not pretty formatted to be displayed for viewers. The viewers will see something different, but value is the same.
- I used `$().closest()` rather than `$().parent()`. Both yield the same result, but because you specified `class="rTableCell"` and `class="rTableRow"` rather than `<tr>` and `<td>`, I figured that was appropriate.
- You can easily add in more columns; I assumed it was fixed and wrote the calculations that way.

So `javascript`, you can add this in the `document.ready` or `DOMContentLoaded`

```
$('.rTableCell').focusout(function(e) {
    /* insert validation here */

    // yield selected row
    var row = $(this).closest('.rTableRow');
    //alternative: console.log($(this).parent())

    // get children (cells in row)
    var rcells = $(this).closest('.rTableRow').children();

    // set HTML to this
    rcells.last().html(calculate_hours(rcells));
})
```

Comment: thanks for response , I will try and let you know mate !